# JS how to concat arrays of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

To be more specific is there a simplier way of doing this:

```
var test0 = [[0,2,4], [1,3,5]];
var test1 = [[6,8], [7,9,11]];

test0.forEach(
    function(item0, index) {
        test1[index].forEach(
            function(item1) {
                item0.push(item1);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

I have tried to use `concat()` at the first level of `forEach()` but it does not work for a reason that still escape me...

Edit:
Thanks for the first answers.
Bonus question, why this one does not work?

```
var test0 = [[0,2,4], [1,3,5]];
var test1 = [[6,8], [7,9,11]];

test0.forEach(
    function(item, index) {
        item.concat(test1[index]);
    }
);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Expected result is given by the example above.

Comment: Should be [[0,2,4,6,8], [1,3,5,7,9,11]]

Comment: I will suggest you using lodash or underscore here

Comment: Second sentence on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) contains answer to your bonus question. (Note that it's not enough to assign to `item` but you have to assign result to `test0[index]`)

Comment: @barbsan thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Benchmark: https://jsperf.com/merge-array-based-on-index

```js
let test0 = [[0,2,4], [1,3,5]];
let test1 = [[6,8], [7,9,11]];
let result = []
for (let i = 0; i < test0.length; i++) {
 result[i] = [...test0[i], ...test1[i]]
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Though what you are trying to depict using JSPerf link is true, try to keep operations as similar as possible. Check: https://jsperf.com/merge-array-based-on-index

Comment: Thanks, changed the answer

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `.map` and spread both arrays, getting the second inner array from the appropriate index in the other larger array:

```js
var test0 = [[0,2,4], [1,3,5]];
var test1 = [[6,8], [7,9,11]];

console.log(test0.map((arr, i) => [...arr, ...test1[i]]));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
var test0 = [[0,2,4], [1,3,5]];
var test1 = [[6,8], [7,9,11]];
test0 = test0.map((a,i) => [...a, ...test1[i]]);
console.log(test0);
```

Comment: Your approach is very similar to CertainPerformance's answer. I guess he beat you to it by a minute. :-p

Comment: @Rajesh - True. I spent some extra time in getting the links :p And obviously, CertainPerformance understood the problem faster.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for an arbitrary count of arrays.

```js
var test0 = [[0, 2, 4], [1, 3, 5]],
    test1 = [[6, 8], [7, 9, 11]],
    result = [test0, test1].reduce((a, b) => a.map((v, i) => [...v, ...b[i]]))

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Looks like you are big fan of reduce function.

Answer (score 1):

`concat` will generate a new array instead of modifying the current array. So in order to make it work, you need to assign the newly generated array back to the parent array on the same index.

```js
var test0 = [[0,2,4], [1,3,5]];
var test1 = [[6,8], [7,9,11]];

test0.forEach(
    function(item, index) {
        test0[index] = item.concat(test1[index]);
    }
);
console.log(test0);
```

Or you can use `map` instead.

```js
var test0 = [[0,2,4], [1,3,5]];
var test1 = [[6,8], [7,9,11]];

var mergedArray = test0.map(
    function(item, index) {
        return item.concat(test1[index]);
    }
);
console.log(mergedArray);
```

**ES6 solution**

I prefer using `concat` to spread syntax because of better readability.

```js
let test0 = [[0,2,4], [1,3,5]];
let test1 = [[6,8], [7,9,11]];

console.log(test0.map((arr, i) => arr.concat(test1[i])));
```